# Swift build error: Expected name of in closure capture list

Tags: ios, swift, build

I'm pretty new to Swift.

I'd love to show dynamic text in a TextView with this code

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var m_logView: UITextView!

    private let m_log = Log()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addLog(msg: "Hello World!")
        m_log.requestData{ [weak, self] (data: String) in   // ### Build error points at this line!
            self.useData(log: data)
        }
    }

    func useData(log: String) {
        addLog(msg: log)
    }

    func addLog(msg: String) {
        m_logView.text += msg + "\n"
    }
}

class Log {
    func requestData(completion: (_ data: String) -> Void) {
        let data = "Data from wherever"
        completion(data)
    }
}
```

But I got a compiler error:

```
Expected name of in closure capture list
```

What does it mean and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is silly TYPO mistake   on `[weak, self]`

Replace your code with

```
m_log.requestData{ [weak self] (data: String) in   
    self?.useData(log: data)
}
```

and as you have used **weak self**, You may use **self?** or unwrap it with `guard let` or `if let`